# Referring to a store's parent/container from the store itself in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, store

I'm actually surprised I haven't found a function that does this yet. What I'm looking for is the equivalent of the component.up() function but for a store. Since store does not inherit from Ext.Component it doesn't have the up() function. However I want to refer to a store's parent inside a load event handler for example. I have found ways to do this like using `Ext.getCmp` or creating the handler from the parent via: `parent.getStore().on("load",handler)` etc but I'm specifically looking for a way to reference to the parent from the store object directly. For future reference mainly.

TL;DR: What is the equivalent of `Component.up()` function for a Store. `Store.up()` doesn't work.

Comment: A store can be bound to many components, so there's no method to get the "owner".

Comment: True but just like a container can have many components and we can refer to each of them via .down(#id) function can't we do the same for a store's parents? I guess not from your answer.

Comment: There is no parent-child concept for stores. Store is not aware where it is used. In other words, store does not know about the view(s) or other stores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have gathered what I am looking for is not possible. Since there are workarounds this is not a problem.

Stores do not have parent-child relationships, thus there are no methods for finding their parent etc. Either use Ext.getCmp if needed to access the parent object or work on the store directly through the parent so that you have scope of it.

EDIT:
If the goal is to execute some logic after the store triggers an event, then we can use the `relayEvents` features to handle the store's events from the parent object, thus having access to it.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly easy to work around. In your window where you create the store, simply do this:

```
{
     xtype: 'treepanel',
     height: 470,
     itemId: 'treepanel',
     name: 'treepanel',
     useArrows: true,
     anchor: '100% 100%',
     rootVisible: false,
     store: Ext.create('Pad.store.LocationTreeStore', {
         parent: this 
     })
}
```

Then, in your controller, in the onLoad event for example of the store, you can now obtain the proper window instance by just asking: store.parent and then query whatever itemId or the like you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's an antipattern the same as referencing a view in a model would be. You want to try for the view components triggering store behaviors instead of vice versa.

One reason is you'd have to potentially create the component before the store, so when the store is initialized it will have a good reference. Even if the reference is in a handler--like load--you sabotage abilities like using autoload and letting the store load data asynchronously while the component is not yet created or rendered.

Also, if you create and destroy components you'll have to update the store with those changes. Also, multiple components using the same store will be problematic without workarounds.

For example, if you have a combobox and a remote store that you want to initialize with the first value, your temptation might be to do that in the store's load handler, when it would be better in the combobox's `afterRender` handler.

```
{
    xtype: "combobox",
    id: "rolesBox",
    alias: "widget.rolesbox",
    store: Ext.create("MyApp.store.users.Roles"),
    listeners: {
        afterRender: function (combobox) {
            this.select(combobox.store.getData().items[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

If your concern is DRY, where you might have one store but many comboboxes, and you don't want to have to put that handler in all of them, you can make an extension with the handler and then create instances of that extension instead.